# Getting author URL outside the loop

Tags: theme-development, author, author-template

I am trying to get author information in my `header.php`.

This is what I use to display the name and it works like a charm:

```
<?php $author_id=$post->post_author; ?><?php echo the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id ); ?>
```

I also wanted to get the author's URL so I changed the code to

```
<?php $author_id=$post->post_author; ?><?php echo the_author_meta( 'user_url' , $author_id ); ?>
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: What are you hoping to get the author *for*? Which post?

Answer (score 2):

I just put a piece of code from [`author.php`](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwelve/1.1.1/author.php#L1) file of `TwentyTwelve` theme:

```
<?php
    /* Queue the first post, that way we know
     * what author we're dealing with (if that is the case).
     *
     * We reset this later so we can run the loop
     * properly with a call to rewind_posts().
     */
    the_post();
?>

<header class="archive-header">
    <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Author Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( "ID" ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_author() ) . '" rel="me">' . get_the_author() . '</a></span>' ); ?></h1>
</header><!-- .archive-header -->

<?php
    /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
     * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
     * we can run the loop properly, in full.
     */
    rewind_posts();
?>
```

Pay attention to how they get an author posts link. At the beginning they call `the_post` function outside the main loop to fetch first post. Then they get author information, like posts URL and display name. And finally they call `rewind_posts` function to reset loop.

You can use the same technique in your `header.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_author_posts_url()` function to get the author link outside of loop.

```
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;

echo get_author_posts_url($author_id);
```

Comment: Note that this retrieves the URL to the author page for the user, and not the URL to their website they added in their profile.

Answer (score 0):

`the_author_meta( 'user_url' )` will retrieve the website URL as set in the author's profile. You need to use `the_author_meta( 'url' )` to display a link to the author post archive:

```
<?php
global $post;
$author_id = $post->post_author;
the_author_meta( 'url' , $author_id );
?>
```

Also note that you don't need to `echo` anything, as `the_author_meta()` already displays it for you.

Comment: It is giving me page permalink

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: still the same giving me page permalink

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_the_author_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_link) function to get the url pointing to the author.

Also you can use [`the_author_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_link) to display the author link.

**Edit**

You might get help with [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-get-author-id-and-user-profile-outside-wordpress-loop/).

Ex.

```
<?php
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
$field='user_url';
the_author_meta( $field, $author_id );
?>
```

Comment: as i said 
i am using the codes outside the loop